# Maintain vector graphics when rendering CALayer into PDF output

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, pdf, calayer

I am rendering a plot with many data points into a CALayer that is hosted by an NSView. All drawing operations done within drawInContext: of the CALayer are vector operations (CGPaths etc.).

Now I would like to export this as a PDF file. Using CGPDFContextCreateWithURL(), a PDF file is created, but it essentially just contains a screenshot of my plot, meaning a bitmap image of the the contents of the view.

But what I want is vector-based PDF. I know that CALayers render their content offscreen into a bitmap which is then shown on screen, but why is it not possible to render the very same content as a vector graphics instead?

Is there really no built-in way to achieve this? I must not be the only one needing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to rewrite your code, the code that draws on the CALayer context should draw also on the PDF context, do not render the CALayer on PDF context because you will get the bitmap output.

Comment: Many thanks, you are absolutely right. I always used "renderInContext:" instead of "drawInContext:". This solved the problem. Unfortunately, the sublayers are not rendered automatically, like in an NSView. So I will have to implement a method which traverses the layer tree and renders each of them.

Comment: One remark: If I want to export a pdf from a layer that is currently displayed in a window, is there a way to make it properly fill the frame of the delivered CGContextRef? Because it maintains the frame of the screen-CALayer and I would like to avoid having to (visibly) change the frame of the displayed layer just for exporting purposes.

Comment: When you create the PDF context you can set the page media box to match the size of your layer if you want to get a 1:1 PDF export.

Comment: That's the point, I want to scale it differently for the export.

Comment: In this situation you need to apply a scale transformation on the PDF context before rendering any content on it.

Comment: @tungsten - any chance you can provide sample code for how you made the changes to get vector graphics in the PDF document.  I am trying to achieve the same thing but not sure of the best way to restructure the code so that the same drawing code can be used for either the PDF context or the UIView context.  Any suggestions would be useful.

Comment: I don't think this is correct if you are using CAShapeLayer.